# Basic login script with stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

Im working on a login script, it used to work few weeks ago but I didn't know why it does not works anymore. The code seems right to me, at least Im sure that the stored procedure is ok (I tested it on mysql workbench). Let me show you the code:

I think the problem is here:

```vb
set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_count", 2, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
```

but I cant figure out how to solve it, any hint would be very appreciated, tyvm.

I tried to write this line in the code:

```vb
Response.Write ("<p>" & v_count & "</p>")
```

to see what output I get, and it's always "7", independently by the account that I use to login.

```vb
<%
' *** LOGON
'LoginAction = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
'If Request.QueryString<>"" Then LoginAction = LoginAction + "?" + Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
session.Contents.RemoveAll()

'Response.Write "HERE"
'Response.End
Dim oggconn
Dim valUsername
Dim valPassword
Private v_count
valUsername=CStr(Request.Form("Login"))
valPassword=CStr(Request.Form("Password"))
v_count=0
if valUsername<>"" then

   Set oggconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
       oggconn.Open (MM_cn_STRING)

   set command = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
       command.ActiveConnection = oggconn
       command.CommandText = "get_dati_user"
       command.CommandType = 4
       ' parametri di input
       ' formato: nomecampo, tipo, tipo di parametro, lunghezza, valore
       ' set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@username", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, username)

       ' parametri di output
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_login", 202, 1, 40, valUsername)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_pass", 202, 1, 40, valPassword)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_count", 2, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_ID_Utente", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_Nome", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_Cognome", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_Email", 202, 2, 100)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_isAdmin", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_isUser", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_isSupAdmin", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_CanView", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_CanMod", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_CanConfirm", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_CanDel", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   set objParameter = command.CreateParameter ("@v_Funzione", 202, 2, 40)
       command.Parameters.Append objParameter
   ' execute per eseguire senza avere un recordset di ritorno
 command.Execute 
 v_count = command.Parameters("@v_count").Value

 ' ricavo l'userID appena inserito

             if v_count <> 0 then
                  Session("Login")=valUsername
                  Session("PWD")=valPassword
                  Session("ID_Utente") = command.Parameters("@v_ID_Utente").Value
                  Session("Nome") = command.Parameters("@v_Nome").Value
                  Session("Cognome") = command.Parameters("@v_Cognome").Value
                  Session("CanView") = command.Parameters("@v_CanView").Value
                  Session("CanMod") = command.Parameters("@v_CanMod").Value
                  Session("CanConfirm") = command.Parameters("@v_CanConfirm").Value
                  Session("isAdmin") = command.Parameters("@v_isAdmin").Value
                  Session("isUser") = command.Parameters("@v_isUser").Value
                  Session("isSupAdmin") = command.Parameters("@v_isSupAdmin").Value
                  Session("Email") = command.Parameters("@v_Email").Value
                  Session("CanDel") = command.Parameters("@v_CanDel").Value
                  Session("Funzione") = command.Parameters("@v_Funzione").Value
                  Session("MM_cn_STRING")=MM_cn_STRING
                  Session("Id_Int")=""
                  Session("Operazione")=""
                  Session("vcount")=v_count
                  oggconn.Close
Response.Write ("<p>" & v_count & "</p>")
Response.Write ("<p>" & valUsername & "</p>")
Response.Write ("<p>" & valPassword & "</p>")
Response.Write ("<p>" & Session("Cognome") & "</p>")
                  ' response.redirect("Main_Menu.asp")
              else
                  oggconn.Close
                  response.redirect("Main_Message.asp?ID=LOGON_FAILED")

             end if
 else

end if
%>
```

The code should fetch the record of the account that I use for the login, but I can login whatever I put in my textbox because the value of v_count is always 7. It change if I change the value in : ("@v_count", 2, 2, 40). How can I make it fetch the correct id of the user from the db?
 This is the stored procedure, I tested it on the workbench and it seems to work as expected:

```vb
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_dati_user`(
IN v_login VARCHAR(45),
IN v_pass VARCHAR(45),
OUT v_count int,
OUT v_ID_Utente VARCHAR(45),
OUT v_Nome VARCHAR(100),
OUT v_Cognome VARCHAR(100),
OUT v_Email VARCHAR(100),
 OUT v_isAdmin VARCHAR(45),
 OUT v_isUser VARCHAR(45),
 OUT v_isSupAdmin VARCHAR(45),
 OUT v_CanView VARCHAR(45),
 OUT v_CanMod VARCHAR(45),
 OUT v_CanConfirm VARCHAR(45),
OUT v_CanDel VARCHAR(45),
OUT v_Funzione VARCHAR(500)
)
BEGIN

select t_utenti.ID_Utente into v_count 
from t_utenti where t_utenti.login=v_login and t_utenti.pwd =v_pass;

 if (v_count >0) THEN
 SELECT
 ID_Utente,
    Email,
    Nome,
    Cognome,
    CanView,
    CanMod,
    CanConfirm,
    isAdmin,
    isUser,
    isSuperAdmin,
    CanDel,
    Funzione
    into
     v_ID_Utente,
 v_Email ,
 v_Nome ,
 v_Cognome ,
 v_CanView ,
 v_CanMod,
 v_CanConfirm,
 v_isAdmin ,
 v_isUser ,
 v_isSupAdmin ,
v_CanDel,
v_Funzione
FROM t_utenti where t_utenti.Login=v_login and t_utenti.pwd =v_pass;

END IF;

end
```

Thank you for reading this

Comment: We don't have your stored procedure code, and we don't have where you put value into v_count variable.  Show us more code so we can help you.

Comment: @DanB `v_count = command.Parameters("@v_count").Value`

Comment: This has some really bad practices going on, especially passing clear text passwords into a database. But without even looking at that, the way this is coded is screaming out for a refactor. If the stored procedure execution always returns `7` you need to test execution of the stored procedure outside of the script using an external program passing the same exact parameters.

Comment: I added the stored procedure in the question, I tested it with mysql worbench and it seems to work, I dont get that 7, just the record that I used for the login. Passing clear text passwords into a database is a problem that I will try to solve later, I'm still learning how to do it. Yeah, I know it's a mess and I will try to improve this, any help is really appreciated xD.